# Can't exploit properly an array with twig

Tags: arrays, symfony, loops, twig

I created an entity that I want to use to save events such as "[this user] accepted / declined the mission". So far I have no problem to save the event, but I'm having issues to display it as a list in the mission's view

I created a loop so that every line from the log's table should show if the the mission's id saved with the rest of the log's line match with the current mission

```
    $history = array();
    $log = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MissionBundle:Log')->findAll();
    foreach($log as $l){
        if($h->getMission() === $mission->getId()){
            $history['user'] = $l->getUsername();
            $history['action'] = $l->getAction();
            $history['day'] = $l->getDay();
        }
    }
```

At first, instead of using `$history['action'] = $l->getAction();`, I tried with `array_push($history, $l->getUser(), $l->getAction(), $l->getDay());`, but the result i got was unusable, since The twig dump I get in result that looked like the following:

```
0 => "Isitech"
1 => "defined the mission as filled"
2 => DateTime {#1421 ▶}
3 => "Isitech"
4 => "defined the mission as declined"
5 => DateTime {#1426 ▶}
```

So with the `$history['user']` thing that I used, I now have the following twig dump:

```
array:3 [▼
  "user" => "Isitech"
  "action" => "defined the mission as declined"
  "day" => DateTime {#1426 ▶}
]
```

I currently have two issues: first, I'd like to create a loop so that I can display every log's line as following:

```
 {% for h in history %}
 {{ h.user }} {{ h.action }} on {{ h.day | date }}
 {{ endfor }}
```

For an unknown, with this loop and how it's displayed in twig, I can't call anything by using {{ h.user }} without getting a message telling me that "user doesn't exist. Moreover, if I do {{ dump(history) }}, I get (i.e.) "isitech" and not [user] => "Isitech", so I can't use the data

Moreover, I currently have two entries in my logs about the same user, but I manage to have only one.

I think I'm missing out something but I can't find where, how and why..

Any idea?

Comment: Well ... this is very confusing. Can you explain it better?

Comment: Edited my question, tell me if you understand better, I apologize, I had a long and rough day :')

Comment: Are you looping through the log or the history in the template? From the code example and error messaages it looks like you're looping through the history, which means each `h` is the value from your history array: the user, the action, and the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I went too far in my loop, and this is why I couldn't have more than one result.

Instead of setting each column by their name and hoping that I'll get my column time the number of existing logs, I simply recreated my loop as following:

```
$log = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MissionBundle:Log')->findAll();
foreach($log as $l){
    if($l->getMission() === $mission->getId()){
            array_push($history, $l) 
            //So we're putting an array result directly in an other array
    }
}
```

With this way, I can now use $history to loop on 'h' and show what I want with 'h.day' for example. Thank you for your help, it helped me finding what was wrong in my code !

Answer (score 2):

Your php loop creating populating the array `$history` is confusing. Many variables are unknown to us.

But you can filter your logs entities with the doctrine's query builder.

```
$logsOfMission = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("MissionBundle:Log")
    ->createQueryBuilder('l') // I create the query builder
    ->where('l.missionId = :id') // Tell him I want only logs of the mission id 'id'
    ->setParameter('id', $myMissionObject->getId()) // I bind 'id' with the id of my mission object
    ->getQuery() // Give me my query doctrine please (the query object returned by doctrine)
    ->getResult() // Thanks :D (access to the attribute containing the query's result)
;
```

Then use the `$logsOfMission` array in twig instead of the history one.

You can learn more about the possibilities offered by [Doctrine and Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html)

**Edit**

After reading again, I assumed there were some typos in your code.

Basing on this:

```
foreach($log as $l) {
    if($l->getMission() == $mission->getId()) {
        $history['user'] = $l->getUsername();
        // ...
```

You were missing the creation of the array for each lines

```
foreach($log as $l) {
    if($l->getMission() == $mission->getId())
        $history = array(
            'user' => $l->getUsername(),
            'action' => $l->getAction(),
            'day' => $l->getDay()
        );
    }
}
```